# JavaScript: Zooming & focusing in on an image

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find a good JavaScript solution for the following problem, but haven't had any luck yet.

I have a series of images arranged in a table on a page. I would like for a user to be able to click on an individual image, and first focus/center the browser on that image, secondly zoom in.

So an example of the html would be something like

```
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td>img</td>
      <td>img</td>
      <td>img</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>img</td>
      <td>img</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of [lightbox scripts](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lightbox) available.

Most notably this one.

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: A lightbox is not what I'm looking for. Think of these images as a comic strip. As a user clicks on each "box" in the strip, I want the browser to center to that box and zoom in.

I do not want to open a new window, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good write up on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/3075-anythingzoomer-jquery-plugin/) about a plugin called the [AnythingZoomer](https://github.com/Mottie/AnythingZoomer) works very well in my early testing.

Might give that a shot.

Comment: Same as above, not really what I'm looking for.